# New dialog in WiX, clicking Back skips the dialog

Tags: wix, dialog

I'm newbie in WiX and trying to customize dialog queue by adding the new one. The new dialog's name is ServerChoice and the flow is:

SetupTypeDlg <-> Full or Typical <-> ServerChoice <-> VerifyReadyDlg

or

SetupTypeDlg <-> Custom <-> CustomizeDlg <-> ServerChoice <-> VerifyReadyDlg

The only problem is in the first case at VerifyReadyDlg. 'Back' takes me to SetupTypeDlg and skips ServerChoice although in the second flow it works as required.

Source:

```
<UI>
        <DialogRef Id="ServerChoice" />
        <Publish Dialog="SetupTypeDlg" Control="TypicalButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="ServerChoice">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="SetupTypeDlg" Control="CompleteButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="ServerChoice">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="ServerChoice">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="ServerChoice" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="ServerChoice">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="ServerChoice" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg" Order="1">WixUI_InstallMode = "InstallCustom"</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="ServerChoice" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="SetupTypeDlg" Order="2">WixUI_InstallMode = "InstallTypical" OR WixUI_InstallMode = "InstallComplete"</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="ServerChoice" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg" Order="3">WixUI_InstallMode = "Change"</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="ServerChoice" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="4">WixUI_InstallMode = "Repair" OR WixUI_InstallMode = "Remove"</Publish>
    </UI>
```

Some help for a newbie? :)

Comment: It seems to me there is some missing information here. If you are also including a WiX supplied publish entries then there would be 2 Publish entries for VerifyReadyDlg Back Button. You might try looking at the ControlCondition table of the MSI using Orca or InstEdit, or use Wix's dark.exe to decompile the MSI and look at the resulting WiX file to make sure you don't have multiple events for the VerifyReadyDlg back button.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Seems you are right, I found the following:

    VerifyReadyDlg | Back | NewDialog | SetupTypeDlg | WixUI_InstallMode = "InstallTypical" OR WixUI_InstallMode = "InstallComplete" 
and  

    VerifyReadyDlg | Back | NewDialog | ServerChoice| 1

How can I remove the first one using WiX?

Comment: grrr... can't make it out as a code. Which tag should I use? Gone to read manuals...

Comment: `VerifyReadyDlg | Back | NewDialog | SetupTypeDlg | WixUI_InstallMode = "InstallTypical" OR WixUI_InstallMode = "InstallComplete"` 
and 
`VerifyReadyDlg | Back | NewDialog | ServerChoice| 1 How can I remove the first one using WiX?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What type of UI are you referencing (Mondo?). This information is not present in your piece of code. I think daddyman's comment is right, you probably have multiple events for that Back button, since Mondo itself hooks its own 'handlers' on this button-click event.

I have created a custom UI dialog flow recently and my approach was not referencing WiXUI_Mondo at all. Instead of it, I created my own new UI based on Mondo source code (you have to check WiX sources). At the end I have this code (irrelevant code parts have been removed) and it works fine.

```
<Fragment>  
    <!-- this is based on the WixUI_Mondo dialog set -->
    <UI Id="WixUI_MyNewUI">
        <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
        <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="12" />
        <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />

        <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />
        <Property Id="WixUI_Mode" Value="Mondo" />

        <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
        <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
        <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
        <DialogRef Id="MsiRMFilesInUse" />
        <DialogRef Id="PrepareDlg" />
        <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
        <DialogRef Id="ResumeDlg" />
        <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />

        <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg">1</Publish>
        <!-- we do not use the SetupTypeDlg which allows user to choose either Typical, Complete or Custom installation; this ensures InstallCustom schema is run -->
        <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Property="WixUI_InstallMode" Value="InstallCustom" Order="2">1</Publish>

        <Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg" Order="2">WixUI_InstallMode = "InstallCustom"</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MyDlg1">1</Publish>

        <Publish Dialog="MyDlg1" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="1">MY_CONDITION_PROPERTY = 0</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="MyDlg1" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MyDlg2" Order="2">MY_CONDITION_PROPERTY = 1</Publish>

        <Publish Dialog="MyDlg2" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="1" />
        <Publish Dialog="MyDlg2" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MyDlg1">1</Publish>


        <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MyDlg1" Order="1">WixUI_InstallMode = "InstallCustom" and MY_CONDITION_PROPERTY = 0</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MyDlg2" Order="2">WixUI_InstallMode = "InstallCustom" and MY_CONDITION_PROPERTY = 1</Publish>      
    </UI>

    <UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
</Fragment>
```

Comment: Thanks. You code helped me to find the shortest solution. Adding Order="2" solves the problem. The correct entry is:
`<Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="ServerChoice" Order="2">1</Publish>`

Answer (score 0):

I think from your fragment that you are trying to do it in a just UI section and I don't believe that is possible. Take a look here http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.com/2008/08/customised-uis-for-wix.html I think it should help.